# Speeding up explorer.exe global shortcuts

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, cygwin, shortcuts, zsh

I'm running Cygwin on windows with cmder as a terminal for zsh.
The way I got it to be a bit similar to what my linux setup has is I placed a shotcut (.lnk) on my desktop with a keyboard shortcut (which I assume is handled by explorer.exe) for <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>.
However, when I use the shortcut, the startup time is enormous (same for mintty), multiple seconds at least. At the same time, starting off by simply clicking the icon twice results in near instantaneous startup.
Why is this the case, and is there any faster alternative to starting up a terminal?

---

Moved to AutoHotKey as a long-term solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem probably arises, because the global shortcut does not start a new program instance if there is already one running.

I use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) for global keyboard shortcuts, because I have it running anyhow. With this small configuration (`AutoHotkey.ahk`), `CTRL+ALT+T` starts a new Cygwin shell via `C:\Cygwin\cygwin.bat`:

```
^!t::Run C:\Cygwin\cygwin.bat
```

Another approach is mentioned [there](http://earthwithsun.com/questions/370535/how-to-make-windows-custom-keyboard-shortcut-launch-new-program-instance-every-t):

Pin the Shortcut to the taskbar and use `SHIFT+WINDOWS+3` (if it is the 3rd item) to start a new instance.

Comment: I'm talking about cold startup time, when there isn't a single instance running. A screenshot of the global shortcut system I'm referring to is available here: http://puu.sh/9nBpC/ab69d2d01e.png
I will look into AutoHotKey, but I'd like to figure this out before that.

Comment: Yes, I've got your point. However a quick test on my machine gives a fast startup with these two methods proposed. Have you tested the `SHIFT+WINDOWS+NUMBER` method -- this should be very easy to check.

Comment: Shift+Windows+Number does improve startup time, but I like to keep my taskbar clean, so it's not a long-term solution.

Comment: This seems to be a general windows issue (see possible duplicate comment above), so I really suggest you give Autohotkey a try, it very handy for other things as well. And yes, you can hide the systray icon with `#NoTrayIcon`, if this disturbs you -- me too... `;)`